# How to scrape specific data from paragraph using htmlAgilitypack?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am scraping data using htmlAgilityPack and its working fine. now in a case i have to  scrap description from paragraph p tag. and paragraph p tag contains description like below

```
<p>
 <small><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;
  created by: created by: Roxy
 </small><br><br>
 its a very nice thing<br>
 it is very useful<br>
 you can get it very easily.                    
</p>
```

now from this paragraph i just want description but don't want to get contains from small tag and also i want to avoid blank spaces and other words from description. 
currently i used code to get it is

```
string Description = pagecontent.SelectSingleNode("p").InnerText.Replace("\n", "").Replace("  ", "") and i got description like
```

" "&nbsp";created by:created by: Roxy its a very nice thingit is very usefulyou can get it very easily."

but i just want 
"its a very nice thing. it is very useful. you can get it very easily."

Comment: i can not understand just because of grammar mistake for 2 words why my question is down voted? why this people want to show that they are over smart?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below:

```
string Description =
    string.Join(
        "",
        pagecontent
            .SelectNodes("//p/text()")
            .Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())
    );
```

Comment: yes dear its working , but it gives text also from another p tag from main page which is outside of pagecontent. in pagecontent i have scraped only specific div from html page but your query written text also from another p tag which is outside of pagecontent and its written with "&nbsp". i want space instead of "&nbsp".